# Direct Dependency Injection and Logger

Tags: object-oriented-design

Lets say I use Dependency Injection and don't use a DI framework. So the injection is direct rather automatic. How I should handle the logger class? All the objects, (thousands) should have a Logger reference in their constructors? (We don't consider Singletons and Service Locater as they hide the dependency, and are pathological liars.)

Comment: As you don't use a framework you're in the plesent position of being able to use DI when it makes sense and not when it doesn't. So does DI give you anything here? If not don't use DI for this.

Answer (score 1):

> How I should handle the logger class?

You should instantiate it and inject it into stuff that needs it.

> All the objects, (thousands) should have a Logger reference in their constructors?

So what? If those objects need to log, then they need to get that dependency *somewhere*.

I would argue that have such pervasive dependencies is a smell, even for logging.

Comment: ++ the question here is, "What do you really, actually, need to log?" [The Case of the Black Enamel Box](http://thecodelesscode.com/case/103).

Answer (score 0):

You basically have two options.

## Use the composition relationship

You would't pass a class implementing a `Log` interface to a class, but you would create an `abstract class` where, in its constructor, you directly initialize it's `protected Log` member with `new` instance of your class implementing the `Log` interface.

All classed which need to use the logger will then inherit this class and if you at any time in the future need to change the procedure of loggin mechanism, you can just swap out the one `new` in your `base abstract class` to a new logger and the change will be propagated throughout all your classes.

## Use static methods

Logging is such a simple task, it produces no side effects. It merely opens a stream to log (be it a database or a file) and flushes the log contents there.

Because of its simplicity, logger can go into the utilities package.

**However, there is one problem.** If you, at any time in the future, decide, you want to change the way processes are logged, you will have to alter the logger class and its logging methods. In this process you are either very likely to lose the initial logging mechanism or going to comment out code for the initial procedures, which will make your code messy.

---

Where I work, we use the first approach - a simple logging interface, containing methods like `logInfo` or `logError` and have classes implement the interface.

Even though we usually restrain from the composition relationship, because it is hard to mock, the logger class, as I have said, is so simple, we have made an exception for it, because we still like it a tad more than having a static logger.

Comment: This is a terrible idea that will make any unit tests brittle and slow.

Comment: @RubberDuck Why would the tests be brittle and slow? We have been using the approach for quite some time and have yet to have problems with it.

Comment: Because you have no way to swap out your logging mechanism with one that doesn't hit the file system or a database.

Comment: @RubberDuck of course you do, it's just only possible on a global basis. The question then becomes is that what you want. Everything is a trade off and there are few absolutes

Comment: If you're inheriting from a base class, I fail to see how you could do that.

Comment: @RubberDuck as a random example log4j provides static methods to get hold of a logger and turn it off/on. Anything you want to change on a global basis is easy. It's only when you want to change it on a case by case basis it gets difficult. Usually global state is bad. But if something is global pretending it isn't is if anything worse

Comment: @RubberDuck Why couldn't you swap out the mechanism? Just go to the abstract class including logger, which all the classes that use a logging mechanism inherit, and change the current creation of a class implementing the Log interface with your desired one. Yes, this way you have one global logger, but I personally do not think that is an issue. AFAIK the purpose of a logger is to have all system messages in one unified place, so you can quickly navigate through them in case you are searching for something. Having only one way to log for all application processes fits the requirement.

Comment: @DavidPacker I shouldn't have to change code to run my tests. I'm obviously not going to convince you of that though, so I won't waste my breath.

Comment: @RubberDuck Why do you think you need to change code to run your tests with the approach I suggested? Because I do not need to and I do not do it.

Comment: @rubberduck you don't literally change the code, part of your test start up makes some calls that turn off logging globally (this is exactly the same as a DI framework but the DI framework pretends this isn't what it's doing)